# Slow INSERTs from SQL Server to MySQL Linked Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, replication, linked-server

We're doing a sort of roll-your-own replication from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database to a MySQL 5.1 database.  This isn't true replication, as the MySQL box is acting as permanent storage and the SQL Server is what we're forced to use as a data aggregator.

So, I've written a stored procedure that checks the latest row inserted on my table in question on the MySQL database, populates a temporary table on the SQL Server end with a new batch of rows to insert back on the MySQL box, and does the inserts.  The problem is, this is painfully slow.  I have a backlog of >24 million rows to send from the SQL Server box to MySQL, and at the rate I'm getting <2 rows/second, it's going to take nearly 6 months to complete and will never be able to keep up with new data as it hits the SQL Server database.

The boxes are not on the same network--the MySQL box sits pretty darn near the country's connection to the Internet back bone, but the SQL Server box is (for reasons beyond our control) only connected through a business DSL line (not positive of the upstream speed).  If I connect through the command line (as opposed to by querying through the linked server in SQL Server), I'm able to insert rows in the MySQL database at an average of ~0.03 seconds per row.  This leads me to believe that either my stored procedure is just incredibly inefficient, or OPENQUERY/Linked Servers are just inherently slow.  Here is the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @LastSensorLogDateFormatted DATETIME
DECLARE @LastSensorLogDate VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @LastSensorLogMillis INT
DECLARE @LastSensorLogEibaddress VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @SensorLogReplicated BIGINT
DECLARE @counter INT

-- Create a temporary table to store last write 
-- to MySQL database on CASALA-DB01
CREATE TABLE #SensorLogRecord 
  (LastSensorLogDate VARCHAR(30)
  , LastSensorLogMillis INT
  , LastSensorLogEibaddress VARCHAR(30))            

-- Dump result of query on CASALA-DB01 into our temporary table
INSERT INTO #SensorLogRecord
  (LastSensorLogDate, LastSensorLogMillis, LastSensorLogEibaddress )
  (SELECT  date, date_millis, eib_address
  FROM 
    OPENQUERY(MYSQL4, 'SELECT date, date_millis, eib_address 
    FROM cabie.sensors_log_redux ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 1'))

-- Store the last sensor log date and EIB address 
-- from our temporary table into local vars
SELECT 
  @LastSensorLogDate = LastSensorLogDate, 
  @LastSensorLogMillis = LastSensorLogMillis, 
  @LastSensorLogEibaddress = LastSensorLogEibaddress 
FROM #SensorLogRecord

SET @LastSensorLogDateFormatted = 
    CAST((LEFT(@LastSensorLogDate, 20) + 
    CAST(@LastSensorLogMillis as VARCHAR)) AS DATETIME)

SET @counter = 0            
WHILE (1=1)
  BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #RecordHolder (Id BIGINT)

    INSERT INTO #RecordHolder (Id)
      SELECT TOP 1000 Sensor_Id FROM dbo.Sensors_Log
      WHERE Sensor_Id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Sensors_Archivals)
      AND dbo.Sensors_Log.Date <= GETDATE()
      AND dbo.Sensors_Log.EibAddress <> @LastSensorLogEibaddress
      AND dbo.Sensors_Log.Date <> @LastSensorLogDateFormatted

  INSERT OPENQUERY(MYSQL4, 
    'SELECT date, eib_address, ip_address, value, application, phys_address 
    FROM sensors_log_redux_holding')        
  SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, GNH.dbo.Sensors_Log.Date,121),
    GNH.dbo.Sensors_Log.EibAddress,
    GNH.dbo.Sensors_Log.Ip_Address,
    GNH.dbo.Sensors_Log.Value,
    GNH.dbo.Sensors_Log.Application,
    GNH.dbo.Sensors_Log.Phys_Address 
  FROM GNH.dbo.Sensors_Log 
  JOIN #RecordHolder  
    ON (#RecordHolder.Id = GNH.dbo.Sensors_Log.Sensor_Id)

  INSERT INTO dbo.Sensors_Archivals (Row_Id) SELECT Id FROM #RecordHolder

  DROP TABLE #RecordHolder  

  IF (@counter >= 1000000)
   BREAK
END
```

I know that's messy...we've been trying different approaches to getting this to work, so there are probably unused variables, etc.  For what it's worth, just running a that first select query on the linked server takes upwards of 40 seconds.

**EDIT:** Here's my linked server setup:

- Provider: `Microsoft OLE Provider for ODBC Drivers`
- Product Name: `MySQL 5.1`
- Provider String: `DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=192.168.17.5;DATABASE=cabie;USERNAME=ourUsername;PASSWORD=ourPassword`
- Advanced Options:

  - Collation Compatible: `FALSE`
  - Data Access: `TRUE`
  - RPC: `FALSE`
  - RPC Out: `FALSE`
  - Use Remote Collation: `TRUE`
  - Collation Name: `(Blank)`
  - Connection Timeout: `0`
  - Query Timeout: `0`
  - Distributor: `FALSE`
  - Publisher: `FALSE`
  - Subscriber: `FALSE`
  - Lazy Schema Validation: `FALSE`
  - Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions: `TRUE`

Comment: Well, as someone who routinely throws millions of rows between SQL Server and a linked Oracle server daily, using both direct linked server stuff and OpenQuery, I can tell you that linked servers _per se_ aren't inherently slow. Maybe there's something odd in either your procedure or the way the drivery stuff that's propping up your linked server connection is working...

Comment: "MySQL box is acting as permanent storage and the SQL Server is what we're forced to use as a data aggregator" - this sounds very strange. Once money is not an issue, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 is WAY superior to MySQL in programmability and provided features. But to answer your question, you will need to figure out what exactly is the bottleneck here. How is your code on MSSQL performing, how it is being sent to the other server, and how fast MySQL processes it. Inserts on MySQL could be slow if using InnoDB, or if having a lot of indexes on the table.

Comment: two more things: `WHILE (1=1)`? `IF (@counter >= 1000000) BREAK`? maybe `WHILE (@counter < 1000000)`? And there is absolutely no point in your #RecordHolder table.

Comment: @Matt, I would imagine the linked server setup/driver is the cause of the issue, as well.  I've edited my question to show those details.

Comment: @AlexanderMP, money is the issue, and that's not going to change.  Inserts on the MySQL end are plenty fast when accessing it directly (rather than as a linked server within SQL Server), and there is only one index on the table.  Finally, I understand those code semantics are not the best--relics from moving stuff around and trying different approaches.  Either way, those aren't what's causing the problem, unless I'm really missing something.

Comment: Try using Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services. At least it will give you more opportunities to test what is the bottleneck. SSIS packages can be scheduled through Microsoft SQL Server Agent, or you can try to schedule them to run every time they are finished running. This IS integration, so it might help if you use the appropriate tools for this.

Comment: I can't use SSIS, unfortunately, as we're limited to using the Express edition.  I wish I could do otherwise, but my hands are tied by _the man_, as it were.

Comment: @Brennon, well, you should have mentioned you have Express Edition :) Anyway, this is integration, and integration can also be done with web services. I don't like the idea of an infinite-running stored procedure. IDK, maybe you have deadlocks in the database because of this. Using a scheduler (like cron) and a script to transfer data between a web service and a database server. I recommend this as one of the last resorts.

Comment: @AlexanderMP, well, the idea is that the stored procedure _isn't_ infinitely running. ;) I have no idea why `SELECT *` from a single-row table (with absolutely nothing else accessing the database) would cause a deadlock or would take >40 seconds. Is there anything wrong with my linked server that you can see?  Is there any benefit to specifying the System DSN directly instead of manually creating the connection string there?  If so, there's a separate issue with this deserving a separate question.

Comment: @Brennon, is it slow when executed directly on MySQL, or just through the linked server? I assume you have an index on date? (and date_millis? Also I think you may want date_millis in your orderby.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's part of the problem...

`# Provider: Microsoft OLE Provider for ODBC Drivers`
`# Provider String: DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};...`

ODBC is famously slow and you are using it on **both** ends.

An alternative approach would be to write an application in Delphi or C(#).
If this application connects using native client dll's to the database.

I know that Delphi with the open source ZEOS database using the client dll's freely available from Microsoft and MySQL will transfer data many times faster than ODBC will do.

Also C# or any modern programming language that uses **the native client dll's** with SQL will do the job.
Make sure that if you use a in-between program to bridge between the two databases that it does not fall back to ODBC, lots of (mainly older) programming environments do this out of lazyness or cheapness with the same crappy transfer speeds that your getting now.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative approach, though?

Comment: Not me, but you can make it a new question: have 2 databases linked with ODBC very slow, would like to know faster alternatives. Ask away, that's what this site is for :-).